# как в js / react при скачивании csv и открытии в онлайн редакторе-csv русский текст нормально отображается, а если в excel кракозябры

Tags: javascript, reactjs

как в js / react при скачивании csv и открытии в онлайн редакторе-csv русский текст нормально отображается, а если в excel кракозябры

```
const DownloadCsv = ({gridRef}:TDownloadCsv) => {

  const downloadBlob = (blob: any, fileName = 'grid-data.csv') => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  const exportCSV = () => {
    const SEPARATOR = ',';
    const columns = gridRef?.current.visibleColumns;
    const header = columns?.map((c) => c.header).join(SEPARATOR);
    const rows = gridRef?.current.data.map((data) => columns?.map((c) => data[c.id]).join(SEPARATOR));
    const contents = [header].concat(rows).join('\n');
    const blob = new Blob([contents], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
    downloadBlob(blob);
  };
  return (
      <img src={excelImg} alt="" className={styles.download} onClick={exportCSV}/>
  );
};

export default DownloadCsv;
```

код отсюда https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/miscellaneous#csv-export-+-custom-search-box

Answer (score 0):

Так получилось подружить с русским excel

```
 const blob = new Blob(["\ufeff",contents], {type: 'data:text/csv; charset=utf-8,' });
```